# Converting MM:SS varchar to HH:MM:SS then to seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I'm having an issue converting a MM:SS varchar field to HH:MM:SS to obtain total seconds.  The field represents phone duration and comes in as a long string.

```
Phone Duration (MM:SS)
5                             :53
8                             :47                 
NULL             
14                            :11                 
29                            :27                 
5                             :26                 
5                             :38
```

My goal is to convert phone duration to seconds.  So 5:53 would be 353 seconds.  I'm receiving a conversion error and I believe it's due to having minutes greater than 24.

I attempted to first trim the phone duration field and convert it to time.  Then converting the time to seconds.

```
with cte1 as (
  select 
      employee
     ,CAST(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(phone_duration)), ' ', '') as time) as Phone_Duration
  from employee_calls
            )

   select
      employee
      ,(CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, Phone_Duration) AS FLOAT)*24*60) as Phone_Duration_Sec
   from cte1
```

The query above is causing a conversion error.

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."  I believe the issue is related to having minutes greater than 24 causing the value to be out of range.  Any thoughts on how to correctly convert the phone duration field?

Comment: The root of the problem is a poor database design. Storing this is text is not a good way to store this information.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you just need to use `CONVERT` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND,'00:00:00', TRY_CONVERT(time,'00:' + phone_duration))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d6c7427fe315c231f0cdefdecf90f3a)

*Note, this will return `NULL` if you have a value greater than `'59:59'`, however, I have **assumed** you have no such values, as they aren't in your sample data.*

If you do have values greater that `'59:59`, you could this:

```
SELECT V.phone_duration,
       (TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(V.phone_duration,CI.I-1)) * 60) + TRY_CONVERT(int,STUFF(V.phone_duration,1,CI.I,''))
FROM (VALUES('5:53'),
            ('8:47'),
            (NULL),
            ('14:11'),
            ('29:27'),
            ('5:26'),
            ('62:39'),
            ('5:38'))V(phone_duration)
      CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',V.phone_duration),0)))CI(I);
```

Comment: Assuming all the values are numbers here is one thing you could do that would work for numbers greater than 59:59. parsename(replace(phone_duration, ':', '.'), 2) * 60 + parsename(replace(phone_duration, ':', '.'), 1)

Comment: I went for a similar, but different approach, @SeanLange

Comment: Yeah I was just throwing that into the mix. I would prefer try_convert to avoid nasty stuff but then again the source here is rather ugly.